# CORS violation after switching from IIS to nginx

Tags: nginx, cors

I have some static content (CSS / JS) that I used to server using an IIS server. I created an ASP.NET application to hold these files, and inside the web.config I inserted these lines

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Now, I have switched this application to Nginx.

I have set up Nginx 1.10.2 correctly.

But whenever I try to get fonts from Nginx, it blocks the request due to CORS policy violation.

[image]

Taking help from this link (http://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html) I have added these lines to my nginx config file, but still the same problem remains

```
    location / {
        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            #
            # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
            #
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
            #
            # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
            #
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
            return 204;
         }
         if ($request_method = 'POST') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
         }
         if ($request_method = 'GET') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
         }
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        #proxy_cache my_cache;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1;
        proxy_cache_methods GET HEAD POST;
        expires 365d;
    }
```

I am really confused as to why the fonts cannot be downloaded. The funny thing is, my css and js can be downloaded correctly. The problem is with fonts only.

Answer (score 0):

This is Chrome's problem rather than `nginx`'s - [This bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=67743) might have something to do with it.

If you use `localhost` for development only, you can start chrome with `--disable-web-security`. Also, you can try with another browser.